# Samba Constantly accessing hard drive

Tags: samba

I have a machine that is using Samba as both a Active domain controller and file server. Everything seems to work but I notice that my hard drive is constantly being accessed. I used iotop and found samba: task[nbt] pre-fork master is the process that is constantly writing to the drive.  Do I have something set up wrong?? Not enough swap memory or something.  I have not been able to figure this one out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to stop samba from constantly writing to my hard drive.  I noticed the process samba: task[nbt] pre-fork master was the culprit process.  I found out that is a netbios process.  I went into my /etc/smb.conf file and placed the following
disable netbios = yes
No more constant writing of my hard drive. Now I need to find out the repercussions of this change.